# Multiple Background Images | Fallback for <IE9

Tags: layout

I know there are lots of questions about background images but I'm looking for a IE7, IE8 fallback that only uses one of the background images. A little different than what others are looking for.

```
background-color:#ebe2c2;
background-image:url('../images/bg-clouds.png'), url('../images/bg-main-repeat.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat;
background-position:center top, left top;
background-attachment:fixed, fixed;
```

How can I get only "bg-main-repeat.jpg" and all it's properties to apply? Right now IE7/IE8 fallback to the color only. Can I format my code differently so that modern browsers will apply both background images but older ones apply only one. I would prefer not to add more HTML but if that's the only way, it's the only way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of two techniques:

1. CSS "hacks" to force certain browsers to behave differently
2. (Much better) Use the built-in Internet Explorer-only conditional statements, such as:

   ```
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <link REL="stylesheet" HREF="css/ie.css" TYPE="text/css">
   <![endif] -->
   ```

   to specify different CSS for pages rendered in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Oops, I initially wrote it to be used by all IE browsers.  Updated with correct conditional statement...

Comment: I don't care to do it either, but in my opinion, it makes for cleaner code overall, and you don't need to use unsupported "tricks."

Comment: Yeah, it does seem to be the best solution.

Answer (score 9):

you would do this.

```
background:url('../images/bg-clouds.png') center top no-repeat fixed;
background:url('../images/bg-clouds.png') center top no-repeat fixed,
    url('../images/bg-main-repeat.jpg') left top repeat fixed
;
background-color:#ebe2c2;
```

Comment: I think `background-color` old parsers will ignore too because it fall  on second "wrong" `background` and continue parsing next css element.

Answer (score 3):

I used to use conditional stylesheets, but it's much more convenient to use a browser specific html class that will allow you to write browser specific css using just one stylesheet.

REPLACE YOUR STANDARD HTML OPEN TAG WITH THE FOLLOWING:

```
<!--[if IE 7]><html class="lt-ie8 lt-ie9 lt-ie10 ie7"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="lt-ie9 lt-ie10 ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="lt-ie10 ie9"><![endif]-->                    
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!--><html><!--<![endif]-->
```

HERE IS YOUR CSS:

```
/* default css */
.element {
   background-color:#ebe2c2;
   background-image:url('../images/bg-clouds.png'), url('../images/bg-main-repeat.jpg');
   background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat;
   background-position:center top, left top;
   background-attachment:fixed, fixed;
}

/* conditional css */
.lt-ie9 .element {
   background-color:#ebe2c2;
   background-image:url('../images/bg-main-repeat.jpg');
   background-repeat:repeat;
   background-position:left top;
   background-attachment:fixed;
}
```